# Replace value containing quotes with sed command and regex

Tags: regex, bash, sed, replace

I am trying to substitute a new version in my yaml file using sed, but I cannot figure out what I am missing from this statement.

I want to convert

```
version: "x.x.x"
```

to

```
version: "z.z.z"
```

Here is my current sed Statement:

```
sed -i "" "s|version: "[[:digit:]].[[:digit:]].[[:digit:]]"\|version: "${VERSION}"|" file.yaml
```

Comment: Try: `sed "s~version: \"[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]\"~version: \"$VERSION"~"`

Comment: For real-world usage, I'd use [`yq`](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/) for this (or a Python script using one of the several available YAML libraries) rather than `sed`. YAML can be written in lots of syntactically different ways with identical semantics; `sed` can only handle one formulation, whereas YAML-aware tools can correctly read and modify *any* equivalent document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
sed -i "" 's|version: "[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]"|version: "'"${VERSION}"'"|' file.yaml
```

To match one or more digits you may use `\{1,\}` range quantifier after eacg `[[:digit:]]`:

```
sed -i "" 's|version: "[[:digit:]]\{1,\}\.[[:digit:]]\{1,\}\.[[:digit:]]\{1,\}"|version: "'"${VERSION}"'"|' file.yaml
```

**Details**

- `version: "[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]"` - LHS, matches `version:`, space, `"`, a digit, `.`, a digit, `.` and a digit (digits if `\{1,\}` is used)
- `version: "'"${VERSION}"'"` - RHS, replacement, replaces with `version:`, space, `"`, `VERSION` variable contents, and a `"`.

You may slightly shorten the command by using

```
sed -i "" 's|\(version: "\)[[:digit:]]\(\.[[:digit:]]\)\{2\}"|\1'"${VERSION}"'"|' file.yaml
```

where `\(version: "\)` is captured into Group 1 and, inside RHS, `\1` is used to insert it back and the repetition of `.` and digit is done with another group quantified with `\{2\}` (two times) quantifier.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i -r "s@version: [0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+@version: ${VERSION}@" file.yaml
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25743964)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed 's/\(version: "\)[^"]*/\1'"$VERSION"'/' file
version: "z.z.z"
```